# How to apply for linked in permissions for iOS Outh api integration

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, linkedin-ios-sdk

As per following url

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields

**Member profile fields available to Apply with LinkedIn developers**

The following selection of profile fields are only available to applications that have **applied and been approved for the Apply with LinkedIn program**:

Full Profile Fields,
**Contact Info Fields**,
Company Fields,
Publication Fields,
Patent Fields,
Language Fields,
Skill Fields,
Certification Fields,
Course Fields,
Education Fields,
Volunteer Fields,
Recommendation Fields

*

> Where to apply for this application on linked in developer portal. can
>   someone share the url or way to do this

*

Answer (score 0):

Application to Partner with LinkedIn for enhanced API access can be found here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply